# dwr (Direct Web Remoting) check version number in project

Tags: java, dwr

I want to know how can we find the **DWR version number** we are using in our project.

Answer (score 2):

Check the `dwr-version.properties` file inside `dwr.jar`. Example:

```
version: 3.0.M1
scc-info: $Id: dwr-version.properties,v 1.63 2008/02/20 14:53:16 joe_... Exp $
```